# Codegolf regex match

Tags: regex, perl

In the codegold i found this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/34345/29143 , where is this perl one liner:

```
perl -e '(q x x x 10) =~ /(?{ print "hello\n" })(?!)/;'
```

After the -MO=Deparse got:

```
'          ' =~ /(?{ print "hello\n" })(?!)/;
^^^^^^^^^^^^
10 spaces
```

The explanation told than the `(?!)` never match, so the regex tries match each character. OK, but **why it prints 11 times** hello and not 10 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions start matching based off positions, which can includes both before each character but also after the last character.

The following zero width regular expression will match before each of the 5 characters of the string, but also after the last one, thus demonstrated why you got 11 prints instead of just 10.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'ABCDE';

# Zero width Regular expression
$string =~ s//x/g;

print $string;
```

Outputs:

```
xAxBxCxDxEx
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you have a string of n characters there are n+1 positions in the string where the pattern is tested.

example with `"abc"`:

```
  a b c 
 ^ ^ ^ ^
 | | | |
 | | | +--- end of the string
 | | +----- position of c
 | +------- position of b
 +--------- position of a
```

The position of the end of the string can be a little counter-intuitive, but this position exists. To illustrate this fact, consider the pattern `/c$/` that will succeed with the example string. *(think of the position in the string when the end anchor is tested)*. Or this other one `/(?<=c)/` that succeeds in the last position.

Comment: Hm... so it not tries to match characters, but tries to match the "nothing" between characters (and the begin and end)... Can't tell than understand now - but your answer make sense.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following:

```
$x = "abc"; $x =~ s/.{0}/x/; print("$x\n");  # xabc
$x = "abc"; $x =~ s/.{1}/x/; print("$x\n");  # xbc
$x = "abc"; $x =~ s/.{2}/x/; print("$x\n");  # xc
$x = "abc"; $x =~ s/.{3}/x/; print("$x\n");  # x
```

Nothing surprising. You can match anywhere between 0 and 3 of the three characters, and place an `x` at the position where you left off. That's four positions for three characters.

---

Also consider `'abc' =~ /^abc\z/`.

- Starting at position `0`, `^` matches zero chars.
- Starting at position `0`, `a` matches one char.
- Starting at position `1`, `b` matches one char.
- Starting at position `2`, `c` matches one char.
- Starting at position `3`, `\z` matches zero char.

Again, that's a total of four positions needed for a three character string.

Only zero-width assertions can match at the last position, but there are plenty of those (`^`, `\z`, `\b`, `(?=...)`, `(?!...)`, `(?<=...)`, `(?:...)?`, etc).

---

You can think of the positions as the edges of the characters, if that helps.

```
|a|b|c|
0 1 2 3
```